# ChatGPT API Отвечает самому себе, и генерирует ответы пока не закончатся токены

Tags: c#, chatgpt-api

Пишу бота в TG на c# для небольшой компании. Главная проблема в том, что ИИ несет полную чушь из разных слов и символов. Также он не останавливается после генерации первого ответа, и генерирует ответы "Бесконечно"

Пробовал менять токен, писать вопрос на английском.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;

namespace ReengSupport_bot
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TelegramBotClient bot;
        private static string gptApiKey = ""; // В будущем желательно убрать все токены из исполняемого файла, ибо это дыра в безопасности
        private static string gptEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/curie/completions"; // Адрес для отправки запросов. Так легче, чем везде его вставлять.

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bot = new TelegramBotClient("");

            bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
            bot.StartReceiving();

            Console.WriteLine("Успешный запуск бота...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            bot.StopReceiving();
        }

        private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = e.Message;

            if (message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
            {
                string response = await GenerateResponse(message.Text);

                // Проверка, что ответ не пустой и не null
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                {
                    // Отправляем ответ пользователю
                    await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Если ответ пустой или null, отправляем сообщение об ошибке
                    await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Извините, не удалось получить ответ на ваш запрос :(");
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GenerateResponse(string text)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {gptApiKey}");  // Авторизируемся

                var request = new  // создаем запрос
                {
                    prompt = text,
                    max_tokens = 2000  // Если поставить слишком большой объем, то он не будет работать
                };

                var jsonContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request); 
                var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); // Создание и перевод в JSON

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(gptEndpoint, httpContent); // Отправляем POST запрос

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var resultJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // считываем строку
                    dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultJson); // десериализации JSON-строки
                    string generatedText = result.choices[0].text; // GPT может предоставлять нам на выбор несколько ответов. При choices[0] мы выбираем самый первый варинат,
                                                                   // я не знаю как это работает, надо документацию читать очень плотно
                    return generatedText;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для этого есть уже уйма готовых библиотек, советую использовать их. Также у чата есть различные настройки, включая модель, которую вы особо не указываете.

Comment: советую также пересоздать токен для телеграм бота, так как текущий вы случайно "спалили"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Где я что-либо написал про серебряную пулю или бесполезность программистов. ИИ тут используется для умной техподдержки юзеров системы и не более. Я согласен, что это не разум и тот же самый гугл, но своим комментарием вы делу особо не помогли.

Comment: @iikuzmychov Да, не уследил. С токеном вопрос решил. У вас идей нету как мне исправить проблему?

Comment: как вам написали, нужно указывать модель с которой вы хотите работать. Они разные есть. Проще всего воспользоваться готовым nuget пакетом, чтобы не штудировать api docs

Comment: @podpivasic чтобы помочь какому-то делу, надо это "дело" нормально адекватно объяснить. А объяснение в  духе "несет полную чушь"  не говорит о проблеме ничего. Какую чушь несёт, что конкретно пишет, какой ответ об ошибке в Response приходит и т.д.  Описательная часть вопроса нулевая

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я дал исчерпывающую информацию о проблеме. Никакой ошибки не выдает. Вам нужна чушь? Ловите!

Comment: ИИ на слово "Привет" отвечает следующее: семье. Ой, как это плохо. На этой неделе был наш повар-психотературер Леди. Не могу разделаться. Всю весну, ухожу в тишину, если что. Давайте поговорим об отпуске. Люди думают как ты будешь жить в Бруклине…Привет семье. Ой, как это плохо. На этой неделе был наш повар-психотературер Леди. Не могу разделаться. Всю весну, ухожу в тишину, если что.

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать IsNullOrEmpty. Т.к он возвращает true, если в ответе есть хотя бы пробел. На будущее лучше использовать string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()

Answer (score 1):

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Ваш API Ключ для ChatGPT API
        string APIKey = "Ваш API Ключ";

        // Адрес API для отправки запросов
        string endpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";

        // Ваш вопрос
        string message = "How to send all 4 requests (GET POST PUT DELETE) using httpclient in C#";

        // Получаем результат метода и убеждаемся в правильности ответа
        string response = await GenerateResponse(APIKey, endpoint, message);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```

Переделайте метод GenerateResponse таким образом :

```
    public static async Task<string> GenerateResponse(string APIKey, string endpoint, string message) // Передаем сообщение на которое хотим получить ответ, Ваш API ключ, и адрес API для отправки вашего сообщения
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", APIKey);

                // Создаем JSON объект для запроса где указываем модель ChatGPT, переменную которая будет содержать JSON строку для запроса, первое сообщение с ролью system, и второе сообщение с ролью user от пользователя.
                var jsonRequest = new
                {
                    model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                    messages = new[]
                    {
                        new { role = "system", content = "You are a helpful assistant." },
                        new { role = "user", content = message }
                    },
                    max_tokens = 2000
                };
                var jsonContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonRequest);
                var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

                string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Выкидываем все лишнее из ответа, и получаем только ответ на вопрос
                    JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
                    JToken textToken = responseObject["choices"][0]["message"]["content"];
                    string textResponse = textToken.Value<string>();

                    // Возвращаем ответ из метода
                    return textResponse;
                }
                else
                {

                    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

И получаем такой ответ :

[image]